# Keras Layer naming in Model not adhering to TF name_scope prefix

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) of Keras in TensorFlow 1.15. My models are complex and have nested structures, so I was thinking [`tf.name_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope) might allow me to create a nice modular structure with each block having its own unique prefix added to layers in that block. However, I can't seem to get it to work. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = Input((10,))
    with tf.name_scope('block_1'):
        x = Dense(32)(inputs)
        x = Dense(32)(x)
    with tf.name_scope('block_2'):
        x = Dense(32)(x)
        outputs = Dense(32)(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    print("\nLayer Names:")
    for layer in model.layers:
        print(layer.name)

    print("\nModel Summary:")
    print(model.summary())

    print("\nOutputs:", outputs.name)
```

The output I get is:

```
Layer Names:
input_1
dense
dense_1
dense_2
dense_3

Model Summary:
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                352       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 32)                1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 32)                1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 32)                1056      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,520
Trainable params: 3,520
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None

Outputs: block_2/dense_3/BiasAdd:0
```

As you can see, in the very last line if I just print the output layer's name, it seems to adopt the `name_scope` prefix, but if I try to print the Layer names from what is retrieved from the model, it doesn't work. I expected the layer names to look like

```
input_1
block_1/dense
block_1/dense_1
block_2/dense_2
block_2/dense_3
```

Or something like that. Any ideas on how to achieve this, or is there some other mechanism I should know about that is better suited for this than `tf.name_scope`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tf.name_scope` puts *tensor* names into a name scope. If you print `x.name` everywhere you will see the scope's name properly applied, because `x` is a tensor. On the other hand Keras layers are not tensors, so they don't respect the name scope (could they? Sure. Why don't they? I don't know).

You can give names to Keras layers explicitly, e.g. `Dense(32, name='scope_1/layer_1`. I don't know of another option.

Answer (score -1):

```
def vgg_block(layer_in, n_filters, n_conv, i):
    
    for j in range(n_conv):
        layer_in=Conv2D(n_filters, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name=f"block{i}_conv{i+j}")(layer_in)
    
    layer_in = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), name=f"block{i}_pool")(layer_in)
    
    return layer_in
```

```
# define model input
visible = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
# add vgg module
layer = vgg_block(visible, 64, 2, 1)
# add vgg module
layer = vgg_block(layer, 128, 2, 2)
# add vgg module
layer = vgg_block(layer, 256, 4, 3)
# create model
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=layer)
# summarize model
model.summary()
# plot model architecture
plot_model(model, to_file='1-multiple_vgg_blocks.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, show_dtype=True)
```

[image]

[image]